# How can i include program form (created in Designer ) to my QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, plugins, pyqgis

How can I include a form created in Designer in my QGIS plugin?

And how to get controls values (textbox,label,etc)?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to load the .ui file dynamically:

```
    # load the form
    path = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )
    self.optionsDialog = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(path,"options.ui"))

    # restore some options
    self.optionsDialog.spinBoxFrameLength.setValue(2)
    self.optionsDialog.checkBoxBackwards.setChecked(True)

    # show dialog
    self.optionsDialog.show()
```

You can have a look at the corresponding full source code here: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/master/timemanagerguicontrol.py

Comment: Thank you! I was able to download the form, but I do not understand how can I assign, for example, a textBrowser value?

Comment: As posted in the example above: There most likely is a .setValue() function. You have to assign names to the UI parts in Designer, like "spinBoxFrameLength" in the example.

Comment: I can not find where the assigned value "spinBoxFrameLength". <<self.optionsDialog.spinBoxFrameLength.setValue(animationFrameLength) >> is it? what value it takes in this case?

Comment: I have an error occurs. swears at "setValue" . << AttributeError: 'QTextBrowser' object has no attribute 'setValue' >>

Comment: QTextBrowser has a setDocument() function. If you want to write plugins you will have to learn to use the Qt documentation http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextbrowser.html

Comment: I was reading. I do not see a method to display in the QTextBrowser

Comment: I did, but differently. Thank you!